# Applying .click event only to links in a certain div-container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

The code already creates a navigation based on a JSON-file. The url are accessible by writing *data.chapter[].subchapter[].url*, the according title through *data.chapter[].subchapter[].title*

In case you are interested in that part or want the complete code, I uploaded it there: http://fabitosh.bplaced.net/SkriptET_iFrame_v2/

The goal now is to create a right sidebar which shows the links to the next and previous files in the structure. My approach is below.
What confuses me, is that back() is called until subchap is zero, when a link in #left is being clicked on. It should only be called when the previous-link is being clicked on. What do I have to change in order to achieve that?

Thanks a lot already!

```
var chap; //position in the array of the currently open chapter
var subchap; //position in the array of the currently open subchapter

function update_right() {
    var path = data.chapter[chap].subchapter; 

    //Previous Page
    if(subchap > 0) {
        $("#prev").html("<b>Previous:</b><a href='"+path[subchap-1].url+"'>"+path[subchap-1].title+"</a><br/>");
        $("#prev > a").click(back());
    } else { //subchap == 0
        $("#prev").html(""); 
    };
}

function back() {
    subchap--;
    update_right();
}

$(document).ready(function() // DOM needs to exist in order to be able to add stuff in there
{
```

...Navigation being built up...

```
    //------ onClick Navigation
    $('#left > ul > li > a').click(
        function(e)
        {
            chap = $(this).attr("data-chap");
            subchap = $(this).attr("data-subchap");
            update_right();
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Use `$("#prev > a").click(back);` instead of `$("#prev > a").click(back());` Currently you are calling function not assigning it to click handler

Comment: @Satpal: Wow, it works that way. Thanks! Did I understand correctly, that you only have to write the brackets () when you want to call the function at the moment. When you want to assign it to an event, you leave them?

Comment: Yep thats true. You just need to pass reference.